# vue.js html element not updated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Here is the code, that handle the mose move, but label don't update the mouse position ? why ?
this is vue.js 3 code.
i want to update the mouse move poistion xy data display on label.
but it does not work, what's wrong ?

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';


    let mouse_x = ref(0)
    let mouse_y = ref(0)

    onMounted(()=>{
        drawline()
    })

    function drawline() {
        let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(200,200);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e) {
        let x = e.clientX;
        let y = e.clientY;

        mouse_x = x;
        mouse_y = y;
        console.log(x,"," ,y)
    }

    function handleMouseClick(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

</script>


<template>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300" @mousemove="handleMouseMove" @click="handleMouseClick"> </canvas>
        <form>
            <label> {{ mouse_x }}</label>
            <label> {{ mouse_y }}</label>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You should not be using `document.getElementById`, use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs) rather. Also, give a try to that one: https://vueuse.org/core/usemouse/#usemouse

Answer (score 1):

refs can't be written with `=` you must set the .value property of the ref

so instead of `mouse_x = x` do `mouse_x.value = x`

```vue
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
const mouse_x = ref(0);
const mouse_y = ref(0);

onMounted(() => {
  drawline();
});

const drawline = () => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
  ctx.stroke();
};

const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
  const x = e.clientX;
  const y = e.clientY;

  mouse_x.value = x;
  mouse_y.value = y;
  console.log(x, ',', y);
};

const handleMouseClick = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <canvas
      id="myCanvas"
      width="500"
      height="300"
      @mousemove="handleMouseMove"
      @click="handleMouseClick"
    >
    </canvas>
    <form>
      <label> {{ mouse_x }}</label>
      <label> {{ mouse_y }}</label>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It also helps you define refs and reactive object as `const` instead of `let` as you did in this answer. This will prevent you from accidentally trying to set the value. There is usually no reason to use `let` inside the script setup, the only use case I have is a setTimeout that can be cancelled and retriggered.